# Putty ssh terminal - no color when using encrypted home folder

Tags: debian, ssh, linux-mint, colors, putty

I use putty and ssh to connect to my Linux servers. I have a Linux Mint 19.3 server running with encrypted home directory. When I connect using putty and ssh, I decrypt the home directory. But the putty terminal is not showing any colors to provide a better readability of the terminal commands and responses. If I use a second putty terminal and connect open a second ssh connection to the same server. I do not need to decrypt home directory again but in this console the colors are correctly displayed in the putty console.

When connecting to e.g. a raspbian server (without encrypted home directory) putty is always displaying the colors.

What do I need to adjust on the Linux Mint server so that the colors are used in the putty terminal?

Comment: Do the colors come back if you source your shell initialization files after connecting (ex. `. ~/.profile` and/or `. ~/.bashrc`)?

Comment: @steeldriver: Could you please explain your hint a little bit more? I fear I can not really follow you.

Comment: It was a genuine question rather than a hint - my *guess* is that the SSH login shell tries to read your initialization files but fails because they are inside the encrypted home dir, and that maybe reading them after decryption (with a source command) would restore the color terminal settings

Comment: If I use the command `. ~/.profile` after decrypting the home folder, the colors are back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `~/.profile` script needs to be executed after login in with ssh and putty.
Therefore edit the `~/.profile` script in the home folder before decrypting it.

```
$ sudo nano ~/.profile
```

And enter following content.

```
ecryptfs-mount-private
cd /home/username
. /home/username/.profile
```

The above content contains also the commands for decrypting your home folder and changing your working directory to your decrypted home folder. And remember, you need to to ediit `~/.profile` before decrypting your home directory.